# OpenLayers 6: add padding on fit function

Tags: openlayers, web-mapping

I'm trying to apply the padding on [fit function](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_View-View.html#fit) but is seems that there aren't effect. This is my code:

```
var sourceGeoBlog = new ol.source.Vector({
  url: '{% url 'api_geopost' %}',
  format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
});

var geoBlog = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: sourceGeoBlog,
  style: styleFunction,
});

sourceGeoBlog.once('change', function(evt){
  if (sourceGeoBlog.getState() === 'ready') {
    if (geoBlog.getSource().getFeatures().length > 0) {
      var padding = [500, 0, 500, 0]
      map.getView().fit(
        sourceGeoBlog.getExtent(),
        map.getSize(),
        {
          padding: padding,
        }
      );
    }
  }
});

var view = new ol.View({
  center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([4.0863647111, 48.6698370737]),
  zoom: 9,
  minZoom: 7.5,
});

var map = new ol.Map({
  controls: ol.control.defaults().extend([
    new ol.control.ScaleLine({className: 'ol-scale-line', target: document.getElementById('scale-line')}),
    new ol.control.LayerSwitcher({tipLabel: 'layer switcher'}),
  ]),
  target: 'map',
  layers: [
    basemapGroup,
    geoBlog,
  ],
  view: view,
  overlays: [overlay],
});
```

[image]

I can zoom on extents of geoBlog.
What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure it fits given your min and max zoom?

Comment: I have not setted min and max zoom. @TomazicM, do you think is important for padding?

Comment: Does it work without padding? Any errors in the console?

Comment: I've added some new code to my post. In console there aren't errors

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `map.getView().fit` call does not get executed because `sourceGeoBlog.once` event processing function is defined after `geoBlog` vector layer is defined and loaded.

Another thing (thanks to comment from @ahocevar) is wrong call to `fit()` function with three arguments. Function takes only two arguments, size has to be passed as `size` option.

You should define function to be called after layer load before layer is actually defined/loaded:

```
var sourceGeoBlog = new ol.source.Vector({
  url: '{% url 'api_geopost' %}',
  format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
});

sourceGeoBlog.once('change', function(evt){
  if (sourceGeoBlog.getState() === 'ready') {
    if (geoBlog.getSource().getFeatures().length > 0) {
      var padding = [500, 0, 500, 0]
      map.getView().fit(
        sourceGeoBlog.getExtent(),
        {
          size: map.getSize(),
          padding: padding,
        }
      );
    }
  }
});

var geoBlog = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: sourceGeoBlog,
  style: styleFunction,
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately nothing is changed @TomazicM

Comment: Did you try to debug execution of `sourceGeoBlog.once('change', function`? Which part does not get executed?

Comment: I've added a `console.log` for each row of `sourceGeoBlog.once('change', function` and everyone is printed. Maybe is a bug?

Comment: A doubt it's a bug, but one never knows. From here on any further help would be possible only with having an example of GeoJSON data that does not work for you.

Comment: @TomazicM's snippet called the fit() function with 3 arguments, but that function only takes 2 arguments. I edited the snippet, so the code should be correct now.

Comment: @ahocevar Thanks, I completely overlooked this!